# How do I show default user on WSL?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I see that there is a way to set the default user for a WSL distro using

```
ubuntu.exe config --default-user FredSanford
```

But is there a way to *view* the current default user? I can't seem to be able to dig up anything.

Comment: Do you mean a command like `bash.exe -c "whoami"`?  I have WSL2 running on a system here and `ubuntu.exe` command does not exist.

Comment: @Terrance ooooh, I think that might work! Does that show the exact same user as when you first login to your wsl distro? I can't test atm because mine is broken.

Comment: @Terrancebtw, if you do a search on the Windows Store for Ubuntu there are currently 3 of them; 2 have "hard coded" version numbers, and one is just listed as "Ubuntu". I have the latter installed. Depending on which you installed, you can have either a ubuntu.exe, ubuntu2004.exe, or a ubuntu1804.exe.

Comment: Right, those are the installers.  The `bash.exe -c "whoami"` shows you the WSL user and not the Windows user.  The command of `whoami` from Windows should show you a totally different user, like mine shows my first initial, last name all together.  Running `bash.exe -c` means to run a command into the WSL and the `whoami` is the command.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks m8, I think that probably answers my question. If you want to add that as an official answer I'll mark it as the Accepted Answer. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `bash` or `bash.exe` as [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1285385/816190) by Terrance, you'll be invoking the default WSL distribution in your system which may or may not be Ubuntu or desired version of Ubuntu in case you have multiple distributions or multiple versions of Ubuntu. In those scenarios you can specify the distribution instead of `bash` or `bash.exe`, i.e.

```bsh
ubuntu -c "whoami"
```

This would execute the command in default shell in non-interactive mode, i.e., environment variables won't be available at this stage (for example, `SHELL` and `PATH`). You'll get no result if you run

```bsh
ubuntu -c "echo $SHELL"
```

As an alternative of `c` option, you can use `run` as well. From the help page of `ubuntu` (which can be obtained using `ubuntu help`):

```
run <command line>
    Run the provided command line in the current working directory. If no command line is provided, the default shell is launched.
```

The resultant command would be:

```
ubuntu run "whoami"
```

---

#### Footnotes:

- Enclosing command in quotes is optional. Anyway you should escape the special characters (if used anywhere).
- `.exe` is part is also optional after `bash`, `ubuntu` and even `wsl`.
- `ubuntu` command can vary according to the version. For example, if you have installed Ubuntu, command would be `ubuntu` but for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, it would be `ubuntu1804` and `ubuntu2004` respectively.